# How to go to the previous tab in Safari from iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a web app that have a link to launch an app for uploading photos when the link is clicked in iPhone. After the app has uploaded the photo, it called the safari back with the continue url as the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: CONTINUE_URL]]
```

But this will open a new tab in Safari. I would like to load the continue url on the original tab that launch the app instead of opening a new tab. anyone know how?